# Agrupar datos Repetidos en SQL SERVER

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

Estuve husmeando por Internet pero no encontré cómo resolver mi duda. Tengo una base de datos donde se carga el Nombre del cliente, teléfono y patente de su vehículo.

Tenemos un software que utiliza las patentes y le envía al cliente un mensaje con información cada cierto tiempo. Mi punto es, sé cómo agrupar los CLIENTES repetidos en si, pero no se cómo hacer para que al agruparse esos repetidos en una fila, se adhieran también las PATENTES asociadas al cliente.

De esto:

```
CLIENTE | TELEFONO | PATENTE

"stack" |"11012345678"|   "ABC123"

"stack" |"11012345678"|   "ABC125"

"stack" |"11012345678"|   "AB123CD"
```

A esto:

```
CLIENTE | TELEFONO | PATENTE0 | PATENTE1 | PATENTEn

"stack" | "11012345678" | "ABC123"|"ABC125"|"AB123CD"
```

Este proceso, lo realizo con un código de **python** que busca repetidos y va asociando patentes, pero al ir mejorando el script noto que estoy reduciendo gran parte de los procesos del código con sentencias SQL, me surge la duda..

¿Alguno sabe si es posible resolver este problema con una sentencia de SQL SERVER?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Desconozco python, pero lo que haría es, al obtener el resultado de la consulta de clientes, crearía un ciclo y lanzaría una segunda consulta dentro del ciclo, es decir, por cada cliente consulto las patentes relacionadas.

Comment: ¿Lo quieres en una columna o en varias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si sabes el número máximo de patentes que puede tener un cliente, podríamos hacer esto:

Primero preparamos los datos de ejemplo (he añadido alguno más para que sea más completo:

```
create table MiTabla (
  CLIENTE varchar(50),
  TELEFONO varchar(50),
  PATENTE varchar(50)
)

insert into MiTabla VALUES
('stack', '11012345678',   'ABC123'),
('stack', '11012345678',   'ABC125'),
('stack', '11012345678',   'AB123CD'),
('otro', '11012345679',   'ABC123B'),
('otro', '11012345679',   'ABC125B'),
('tercero', '11012345677',   'ABC1232'),
('tercero', '11012345677',   'ABC1252'),
('tercero', '11012345677',   'AB123CD2'),
('tercero', '11012345677',   'ABC123B2');
```

Y ahora ejecutamos la consulta (la he hecho para que el máximo sean 4, pero la podrías modificar fácilmente):

```
with cte
as
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CLIENTE, TELEFONO ORDER BY CLIENTE, TELEFONO, PATENTE) rn,
    CLIENTE, TELEFONO, PATENTE
  from MiTabla
)
SELECT CLIENTE, TELEFONO,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN PATENTE END) PATENTE1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN PATENTE END) PATENTE2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN PATENTE END) PATENTE3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN PATENTE END) PATENTE4
FROM CTE
GROUP BY CLIENTE, TELEFONO
```

Esto devolvería la siguiente tabla:

| CLIENTE | TELEFONO | PATENTE1 | PATENTE2 | PATENTE3 | PATENTE4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tercero | 11012345677 | AB123CD2 | ABC1232 | ABC123B2 | ABC1252 |
| stack | 11012345678 | AB123CD | ABC123 | ABC125 |  |
| otro | 11012345679 | ABC123B | ABC125B |  |  |

Te dejo un DBFiddle para que lo veas en funcionamiento: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af12fa689165d626695d7ac1ad6b8b24

No obstante, si lo que quieres es que se pueda ejecutar desconociendo el número máximo de posibles patentes por cliente, tendrías que hacerlo ya con SQL dinámico. Salvo que lo quieras en una única columna, que entonces no sería necesario conocer el número máximo de patentes y sería así de sencillo:

```
SELECT CLIENTE, TELEFONO, STRING_AGG(PATENTE, ', ') PATENTES
FROM MiTabla
GROUP BY CLIENTE, TELEFONO
```

Que devolvería esto:

| CLIENTE | TELEFONO | PATENTES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tercero | 11012345677 | ABC1232, ABC1252, AB123CD2, ABC123B2 |
| stack | 11012345678 | ABC123, ABC125, AB123CD |
| otro | 11012345679 | ABC123B, ABC125B |

De este último caso (todas las patentes en una sola columna) te dejo otro DB Fiddle diferente: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c5261f68ba776cd25103c0a7fa3d0d11

Comment: Super completa y explicativa!!! Me gusto tu respuesta y me funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo con [STUFF y XML PATH](https://qastack.mx/programming/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server), una consulta y la subconsulta en el SELECT, entiendo que es la misma tabla (tabla_datos la llamo), si no fuera la misma habría que hacer el JOIN correspondiente.

```
SELECT
    dat1.cliente,
    dat1.telefono,
    STUFF((SELECT ","+dat2.patente from tabla_datos d2 WHERE dat1.cliente = dat2.cliente for XML PATH('')),1,1'') AS patentes
FROM
    tabla_datos dat1
GROUP BY dat1.cliente, dat1.telefono;
```